# Can I force jetty to *not* include a Content-Length header for unit testing?

Tags: java, http, junit, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using a simple embedded Jetty instance in some JUnit tests.

I want to force Jetty to return an HTTP response without a Content-Length header (as we've seen happen on certain requests out in the wild).

I currently implement `handle(...)` of `AbstractHandler` as the primary way that I capture requests, then, based on the parameters in the URL, Jetty returns a variety of possible responses, good or otherwise.

`response.setHeader("Content-Length", null);` didn't work, it still returned the valid content length based on my body data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that wraps the [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) with your implementation that prevents the `Content-Length` header from being set.

Be sure to implement the following methods in your HttpServletResponseWrapper.

- [addHeader(String,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [addIntHeader(String,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html#addIntHeader%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- [setHeader(String,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [setIntHeader(String,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html#setIntHeader%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

each of those can be a simple piece of code similar to ...

```
@Override
public void addHeader(String name, String val)
{
    if ( "Content-Length".equalsIgnoreCase(name) ) 
    {
        // Ignore content-length from servlets
        return;
    }
    super.addHeader(name,val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write some bytes or chars to the response, then flush, then write some other bytes or chars to te response, it will have to used a chunked transfer type and won't be able to set the content length, since it's forced to send the bytes without knowing the length of what will actually be written.